# Printing SQLite entries into a ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I am having some  trouble learning the ins and outs of the SQLite world. I have some code that is allowing me to enter data into a DB. But what i want to do is return this data into a listview. At the moment all I could figure out to do was to have each row printed in a toast after a new entry is added. Can someone please show me how to alter my code to print it in a listview? Or to  even look at my code and see that i am going about it in the right way. Thanks

This is the code i am using which calls a display record function

```
    //---get all Records---
    com.example.rory.dbtest.DBAdapter db = new com.example.rory.dbtest.DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAllRecords();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            DisplayRecord(c);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
```

This is the display record function

```
public void DisplayRecord(Cursor c)
{
   Toast.makeText(this,
            "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
                    "Item: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                    "Litres:  " + c.getString(2),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I know i need to change the second function but i dont know how to do that to make it print into a listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the code of getting data from database and insert into Arraylist and insert into arrayAdapter and than display it in listview .

i just done some editing in your  existing code.

```
com.example.rory.dbtest.DBAdapter db = new com.example.rory.dbtest.DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();

ArrayList<String> data_list=new ArrayList<String>();
ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
Cursor c = db.getAllRecords();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            data_list.add(c.getString(0));
            DisplayRecord(c);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data_list);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);
```

lv - is the object of ListView.

Comment: thanks very much this looks like a big help, is this just using the original display function to add the entries into the array??

Comment: no your display function is only for toasting data... the real work is only in arraylist and ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `ListView`. Then provide `cursorAdapter` to the `ListView` as it's adapter to bind the data in the database to the `ListView`.

There are examples in the samples folder of the SDK you downloaded in the project called `ApiDemos`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have, 1) listview, 2) Object class, 3) Custom Adapter

Here I have just tried to implement as per your requirement.
Since I dont have db I did not try to run. The point to is to five you idea. 
Because listview is widget that we use more frequently in android. This is the best approach as per my knowledge.

Layouts that required,

**activity_list.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ListActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**row_item.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Item" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Litres"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="litres" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**ListActivity.java :**

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<RowData> rowDataArrayList = new ArrayList<RowData>();
    ListView list;
    ListAdapter listAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(ListActivity.this, rowDataArrayList);
        list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        getDataFromDB();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void getDataFromDB() {
        rowDataArrayList.clear();

        com.example.rory.dbtest.DBAdapter db = new com.example.rory.dbtest.DBAdapter(
                this);
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllRecords();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                /**
                 * Set your data in class
                 */
                RowData rowData = new RowData();
                rowData.setId(c.getString(0));
                rowData.setItem(c.getString(1));
                rowData.setLitres(c.getString(2));
                rowDataArrayList.add(rowData);

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        /**
         * To reflect new data set change in listview
         */
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**RowData.java :** Model[pojo] class to save data and to bind in custom adapter.

```
public class RowData {
    String Id;
    String Item;
    String Litres;

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        Id = id;
    }
    public String getItem() {
        return Item;
    }
    public void setItem(String item) {
        Item = item;
    }
    public String getLitres() {
        return Litres;
    }
    public void setLitres(String litres) {
        this.Litres = litres;
    }

}
```

**ListAdapter.java :** custom adapter to bind in listview

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<RowData> rowDataArrayList = new ArrayList<RowData>();

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RowData> rowData) {
        mContext = context;
        rowDataArrayList = rowData;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rowDataArrayList == null ? 0 : rowDataArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            Holder holder = new Holder();
            view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.row_item, null);
            holder.tvtItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Item);
            holder.tvtLitres = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Litres);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        Holder holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        holder.tvtItem.setText(rowDataArrayList.get(position).getItem());
        holder.tvtLitres.setText(rowDataArrayList.get(position).getLitres());

        return view;
    }

    class Holder {
        TextView tvtItem;
        TextView tvtLitres;
    }
}
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<RowData> rowDataArrayList = new ArrayList<RowData>();

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RowData> rowData) {
        mContext = context;
        rowDataArrayList = rowData;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rowDataArrayList == null ? 0 : rowDataArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            Holder holder = new Holder();
            view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.row_item, null);
            holder.tvtItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Item);
            holder.tvtLitres = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Litres);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        Holder holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        holder.tvtItem.setText(rowDataArrayList.get(position).getItem());
        holder.tvtLitres.setText(rowDataArrayList.get(position).getLitres());

        return view;
    }

    class Holder {
        TextView tvtItem;
        TextView tvtLitres;
    }
}
```