# ListView using multiple Subitems

Tags: android, android-listview

Hello and again a question about a List this time.. a ListView......

I'm using a BaseAdapter to inflate a layout which includes a RelativeLayout(Parent) and 4 ImagesViews which are alignBaseline(horizontal) to the first ImageView.(It doesn't really matter) They all have the same source, which is an imageArray. The Problem is that the getView-Method only fires for every ListItem created/reused/scrolled into the view..but not for the childs of the ListItem(my ImageViews). So as you already expected:"How can he set the Images to the ImageViews from the same source if getView only fires for every listItem, but not for the childrens of every listitem??".

I stucked here:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView img1;
    ImageView img2;
    ImageView img3;
    ImageView img4;
    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;
    TextView tv3;
    TextView tv4;
    TextView tv_abc;

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customadapter_view_layout, null);
        img1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_normal_portrait_1);
        img2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_normal_portrait_2);
        img3 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_normal_portrait_3);
        img4 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_normal_portrait_4);
        tv1 =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_normal_portrait_1);
        tv2 =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_normal_portrait_2);
        tv3 =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_normal_portrait_3);
        tv4 =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_normal_portrait_4);
        tv_abc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_normal_portrait_abc);
        convertView.setTag(new Holder(img1,img2,img3,img4,tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4,tv_abc));
    } else {
        Holder holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        img1 = holder.img1;
        img2 = holder.img2;
        img3 = holder.img3;
        img4 = holder.img4;
        tv1 = holder.tv1;
        tv2 = holder.tv2;
        tv3 = holder.tv3;
        tv4 = holder.tv4;
        tv_abc = holder.tv_abc;

    }
        img1.setImageDrawable(scaledImage[position]);
        img2.setImageDrawable(scaledImage[position+1]);
        img3.setImageDrawable(scaledImage[position+2]);
        img4.setImageDrawable(scaledImage[position+3]);
        tv1.setText(labels[position]);
        tv2.setText(labels[position+1]);
        tv3.setText(labels[position+2]);
        tv4.setText(labels[position+3]);


    return convertView;
}

}
```

(Please ignore the textViews)
As you already mentioned, this is extremly slow and it doesn't even work. Why? As i mentioned before, Position(from getView) Counts every ListItem but not every Child of the Listitem. Furthermore when i tried this i found out that Position(from getView) only Counts ListItems. And later i thought, how could i be that stupid thinking that the getView knows(or better wants to know) about the Childs in my layout ?? Even more i hate Solutions like that above...they are slow, complicated and often lead into IndexOutOfBoundException.

So please, do someone have a much better solution or a totally different way getting this work.(Other Adapter, whatever). I appreciate every help. Thank you

Comment: If I understand correctly you want the same picture in 4 different image views that are all in the same view? It's not clear exactly what you want to be in the image views.

Comment: nono, let's suppose i have 40 Images, then i want to set the Picture 1 to imageview 1 the Picture 2 to imageview 2 the Picture 3 to imagevie 3 the Picture 4 to imageview 4 and then the next Item in the listview Comes... Picture 5 in ListItem 2 ImageView 1 and so on. But all ImageViews using the same source, the drawable Array named scaledImages. Do you understand? @Developer Paul Any Support would be nice :)

Comment: How exactly are you loading your images? Is the array accesible within the adapter? Also so if you had 40 images, then theoretically you should have 10 list items? Item 1 will have images 1-4 and so on, correct? Also why isn't your current method not working?

Comment: @developer paul what do you mean accessible. I take some images the storage of the phone where pictures are stored scale them and want to display them in the listview. Getting and scaling the app is done in the activity from where i set the adapter to the listview. Is a listview the correct way? If so, how can i easily setup a better solution.

Comment: @Mike Does the position of images that you want to show in the `scaledImage` list is always from 0-3? Or (for example) if the `listview` item is 5 then its 5-8?

Comment: Create model[POJO] class, store value of scaledImage[] in it and access it in getView();, this is the solution for IndexOutOfBoundException. But I can not say about slow part.

Comment: @blaze tama sorry responding that late, but i went to bed. It was really late/early. Yes, i tottaly forgot to mention that. The images in the souce scaledImages are already sorted! So 0-3 goes to the first row..  4-7 to the second. 8-11 to the third and so on.

Comment: @blaze tama missed the point! No, if i got 40images then scaled images length is 40! In other words the images ate located from 0 to 39 in scaled images

Comment: @chitrang i'm really new to android. Please explain shortly what a POJO model class is. What i tried was to create a ''bufferclass'' which got 4 Drawable-Arrays. One for only one item a row for example. BufferImage1[0] contains picture for position 0 in row one on 0. Contains picture on position 4 in row two on Bufferitem[1]. And so on. My problem is i found no logic to add the pictures on GUI on the right position countin from left to right with 4 images per row so 0,4,8.. And so on. Pictures to bufferitem1[].. At sime time adding 1,5,9.. to BufferItem2[]. Hope you can provide a logic. Ty

Comment: Please follow this link and find my answer, you may get some idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700897/printing-sqlite-entries-into-a-listview/26701951#26701951

Answer (score 1):

**POJO**

POJO is actually a java programming term and not necessarily associated only with Android.  It stands for Plain Old Java Object and many other languages have their own equivalent acronym. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) has a nice write up about it.  The idea is needing a very simple class to pass around some data.  The `Holder` you are using is an example of a POJO.

**Counting**

As you mentioned, part of your problem is an slight mistake in understanding how a `BaseAdapter` works.  I'm assuming you had defined the following:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return scaledImage.length();
}
```

When in reality you needed something more like:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    //This assumes you'll ensure the array will always be equally divisible by 4.
    //If not, you'll need to add some empty elements at the end to make it so.
    return scaledImage.length() / 4;
}
```

The adapter is only aware of the number of rows it contains and not how much data in total is used for the rows. Receiving `IndexOutOfBoundsExpections` is not the result of using `scaledImage` as shown in your code.  It's a problem caused elsewhere. Using an array like that is perfectly fine...so long as your `getCount()` method is returning the correct value.

**Applying POJO**

As Chitrang has suggested, you could convert your `scaledImage` array into a POJO. So for example, you'd have something like:

```
private class ScaledImageRow {
    //You could just as easily use an array of 4 elements instead
    Drawable image1;
    Drawable image2;
    Drawable image3;
    Drawable image4;
}
```

Then when you are constructing your custom adapter, you'd want to convert your:

```
Drawable[] scaledImage;
```

into a:

```
ScaledImageRow[] scaledImageRow;
```

By doing this, you can then return the length of the `scaledImageRow` for the count and in your `getView()` obtained the correct row of images by using `scaledImageRow[position]`

Now converting your data over to such a POJO doesn't really by you anything performance wise. What it does more so is increase the readability of your code.  It will also help conceptualize what's going on with your code better.

**Performance**

You mentioned some very slow performance with your `getView()` as depicted in answer. Your array approach is definitely not the cause of it. I would say it's the setting of the images. I'm guessing you've already loaded the images into memory. So perhaps the images are still fairly large and the `ImageView` has some sort of scaling attribute defined in XML? Otherwise, I'd say the slowdown is being caused elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I will Need to understand your hole answere. Cause i'm new to Android. I really think i Need to take a much closer look at the getCount() method! I already googled the pojo and as you mentioned my class Holder is a POJO. But thank you for the additional Explanation of a POJO! Finally i will take a gridview because i Need a onclick-listener on every Image. I really don't want to take more time of you. But if you have fun of it could you provide me the baseadapter code for my issue for better understanding? If not it's ok! I hope the getCount method is my key to success :). Upvote !